# How to list CakePHP Acl ACO and ARO structure?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I want to list the CakePHP Acl database by Acos and whether an Aro has permission yes or no.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the acl shell

Cake has a built in [acl shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html) which provides an interface for modifying or viewing your acl data. It includes a [view (tree)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html#view-the-node-trees) function which permits seeing your access control objects (aco, "things") and access request object (aro, users) data hierarchies:

Example aco tree:

```
$ Console/cake acl view aco

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Aco tree:
---------------------------------------------------------------
  [1] controllers
    [2] Posts
  [3] Posts
    [4] index
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example aro tree:

```
$ Console/cake acl view aro

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Aro tree:
---------------------------------------------------------------
  [1] Group.1
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

There's also a check function for determining if a given aro can access a given aco:

```
$ Console/cake acl check Group.1 controllers/Posts

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Group.1 is allowed.
```

### Who can access what isn't possible

The nature of acl data is that it's relatively expensive to check a single combination (can *this specific user* access *this specific object*) and (though possible) impractical to build a general solution for "who can access what", that's effectively why there's no core-provided means to answer that question.

For a given list of acos though, you can easily loop on them calling [AclComponent::check](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AclComponent.html#_check) to get a list of answers for "what this specific user can access". The acl data can be accessed like any other model data using `Aro` and `Aco` models.

Comment: @YisraelDov I'm not sure of the purpose of your comment. Do you read the answer to suggest doing that? The component method [just calls check on the adapter](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php#L110), which just calls [check on the Permission model](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Model/Permission.php#L74) - if that's what you're trying to do, call the permission model method directly.